# How to declare a variable in MySQL for a normal query?

Tags: mysql, variables, variable-declaration

How can I declare a variable for a normal query in MySQL?

**e.g.,**

```
declare @myVar date;
set @myVar = something;

select * from someTable where someColumn = @myVar;
```

I tried and the syntax seems to be wrong...what am I missing?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can declare a session variable in this way :

```
SET @myvarname := 'value';
```

or a local variable in this way :

```
DECLARE my_variable varchar(30)
```

also:

```
DECLARE my_variable varchar(30) DEFAULT 'value'
```

Comment: I did the same as the last line, then I get this error:  near "DECLARE": syntax error