# Set variable in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, dynamic-sql

I am trying to set variable but I get `Incorrect syntax near '='.`.

```
    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(100) = 'Some name'
    DECLARE @id INT
    EXECUTE ('SET ' + @id + ' = (SELECT mm.mmID FROM dbo.measurem AS mm
        WHERE mm.placeName = ''' + @name + ''')')
    PRINT @id
```

If I try like this:

```
SET @id= (SELECT mm.mmID FROM dbo.measurem AS mm
          WHERE mm.placeName = @name)
```

I get `must declare variable @name` although I have it as my input store procedure param.

Comment: You appear to be using Microsoft SQL Server syntax, but you have tagged your question [tag:mysql]. Which database are you really using? What does `SELECT @@version;` return?

Comment: I am using MS SQL. It is top much 5 tags so I had to put something.

Answer (score 0):

For declaring variable, you can go through [Declaring Variable in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893517/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql-for-a-normal-query)
However you need to do something like this to make it run
[<>db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2466a598eb39bbfed5a6d91dc2c069f7)

```
SELECT @my_name := 'Some name';
SELECT @id;
SET @s = CONCAT (
        'Select mm.mmID into @id From measurem as mm where 
    mm.placeName='
        ,''''
        ,@my_name
        ,''''
        );
PREPARE stmt
FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SELECT @id;
```